# Is there a way to disable anti-aliasing in css?

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with anti-aliasing (I guess) in css.
I've seen how to disable it on fonts and images but I'm having troubles with some borders...
Here's the thing, I have a canvas wrapped by two divs, in a grid display. It renders nicely sometimes but with certain levels of zooms, a gray line appears next to borders. I figured out it was because of anti-aliasing but I can't find a way to disable it.

**With anti-alliasing**
[image: With anti-alliasing]

**What I would like to be always there**
[image: What I would like to be always there]

Comment: Have you tried changing the background color of the parent element that renders between the canvas and divs?

Comment: @jsejcksn I just tried and it didn't change anything but don't worry, I simply changed the design a bit and now, I don't have to deal with it. I even find it better like this ! "It's not a bug, it's a feature." haha

Comment: Could you show us your code or your website please?

Comment: I just changed my design @GucciBananaKing99
I went from [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hFf9.png) to [that](https://imgur.com/a/A8XXXM2) so it's not a solution but since I'm building this alone, it's not a problem for me.